# Kind of weak pointer for unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, libstdc++

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int i = 8;
};

class B {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> p;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.p.reset(new A);
    std::cout << "Out1: " << b.p->i << std::endl;

    const A* const a = b.p.get();

    delete a; // how to forbid this statement?

    std::cout << "Out2: " << b.p->i << std::endl;
}
```

is nonsense and yields nonsense:

```
Out1: 8
Out2: 1587634531
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

How to detect such nonsense at compile time, i.e. how to declare pointer `a` such that it has r/w access to `*a` (of type `A`), but cannot corrupt the unique pointer `B.p`?

The `const` around `A*` are *not* the solution.

In the case of `std::shared_ptr`, we have `std::weak_ptr` - do we have nothing alike for `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. It is logically impossible for a C++ compiler to meaningfully reject a `delete` if some other code that would, eventually, execute beforehand in the final C++ program exists in some other completely different `.cpp` file that the C++ compiler hasn't even compiled yet!

Comment: You could create your own "unique pointer" wrapper class, that in all ways behaves as `std::unique_ptr` *except* that it doesn't allow raw pointer access.

Comment: Please watch this: https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE - basically do not use `new` `delete` explicitly. Note also that `std::unique_ptr` should be a unique owner of object, so your example is invalid.

Comment: As for the problem in your code, this is where static analysis tools and code-reviews help to catch such issues.

Comment: A const reference to the `unique_ptr` might do what you want? You'd still be able to extract the pointer from it and `delete` it though

Comment: @AlanBirtles but maybe since it's not a raw pointer you wouldn't feel a need to `delete` it in the first place?

Comment: I don't see how `weak_ptr` would help – you can perform the same trick with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: That tiny bit of code is, indeed, nonsense. But that `delete` can be valid in other situations, such as `b.p.release(); delete a;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, you can use a static analysis tool to forbid new/delete, setting warnings as errors, and running on pull requests on CICD. In particular, running clang-tidy on your code gives:

```
[build] main.cpp:19:9: error: use std::make_unique instead [modernize-make-unique,-warnings-as-errors]
[build]     b.p.reset(new A);
[build]        ~^~~~~ ~~~~~
[build]         = std::make_unique<A>
[build] main.cpp:19:15: error: initializing non-owner argument of type 'pointer' (aka 'A *') with a newly created 'gsl::owner<>' [cppcoreguidelines-owning-memory,-warnings-as-errors]
[build]     b.p.reset(new A);
[build]               ^~~~~
[build] main.cpp:24:5: error: deleting a pointer through a type that is not marked 'gsl::owner<>'; consider using a smart pointer instead [cppcoreguidelines-owning-memory,-warnings-as-errors]
[build]     delete a; // how to forbid this statement?
[build]     ^      ~
[build] main.cpp:22:5: note: variable declared here
[build]     const A* const a = b.p.get();
```

The warning messages reference the core guidelines, in particular [I.11](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t), and the [support library](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL). However rather than using the support library, it's easier to rewrite directly in terms of `unique_ptr`, `std::make_unique` (as has already been mentioned), and encapsulate pointers in classes.

One possible refactoring is along these lines:

```
class B
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> p;

public:
    void set(std::unique_ptr<A>&& p_) { p = std::move(p_); }
    const auto& get() const { return *p; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    auto p_ = std::make_unique<A>();
    b.set(std::move(p_));
    std::cout << "Out1: " << b.get().i << std::endl;

    const A& a = b.get();

    std::cout << "Out2: " << a.i << std::endl;
}
```

Note, here `a` has become a (const) reference, so can't be deleted.

Footnote: clang-tidy can be set up with CMake using `CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY`, with a .clang-tidy file at the root of the project to enable or disable checks (depending on whether you want to have minimal checks, or run all checks and disable the ones that aren't useful).

Answer (score 2):

Not a tool, but if you completely ban all uses of `new` and `delete`, then this can't occur.

```
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.p = std::make_unique<A>(); // no longer new
    std::cout << "Out1: " << b.p->i << std::endl;

    const A* const a = b.p.get();

    /* delete banned by code review
    delete a;
    */

    std::cout << "Out2: " << b.p->i << std::endl;
}
```